# Why is this my output using index? what is index?

Tags: python, indexing

```
for index in range(0, 10, 2):
    print(index)
```

Why is the output 2,4,6,8?
How is it specified to only print evens? Is this what index does? My understanding was that index means position.

Comment: Did you read the docs on range? index is just the loop variable, you could trivially change it to any valid identifier.

Comment: `index` is simply a variable name. You could've used `for absolutely_whatever in range(0, 10, 2)` instead

Comment: Ok! Thats what I had assumed but I don't understand why thats the output then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was explained in the comments, the word `index` is just a variable name here. Yes, normally index refers to the position of an element in an iterable, however, that is not related to anything occurring in the code snippet in question.

Only the evens are printed as a result of the built-in `range` function. The third parameter, in this case `2`, specifies the "step," which basically says how many numbers to jump for each element in the iterable `range` constructs. Then those elements are iterated over and bound to `index` in order, thus you see your output.

Comment: OHHHH ok! I get it now! Thank you thank you! I didnt know about the parameter thing